# Why Does Java Skip My If Statement in a While Loop?

Tags: java, if-statement, while-loop, syntax-error

I'm trying to construct a program that counts the amount of vowels in a given string. Everything seems to run fine until I get to the while loop. It completely skips my if statement and goes straight to the incrementation of integer r. I feel that this is a syntax error; however, I can't imagine what it could be. Any thoughts?

```
String e [] = {"a", "e", "i", "o", "u"};
String a = "banana";
int r = 0;
int b = 0;
int c = 1;
int z = 0;
String q = " ";
for(int i = 0; i < a.length(); i++) {
    q = a.substring(b, c);
    b++;
    c++;
    while(r < e.length) {
        if(q.equalsIgnoreCase(e[r])){
            z = z + 1;
        }
        r++;
    }   
}
System.out.println(z);
```

Comment: `r` is never reset for one thing

Comment: Try adding `r = 0;` before the `while` loop.  In fact, you'd probably be better using an enhanced `for-loop`

Comment: Thanks so much! Can you explain why adding r = 0 worked? It works and all, but I'm not sure why. Does it have something to do with the syntax?

Comment: After the first loop `r` will be equal to `e.length`...therefore it will never enter the `while-loop` again

Comment: @MadProgrammer why not post it as an answer instead of comments?

Comment: @singhakash Because it's really a simply debugging exercise which the OP should have been encouraged to try and solve themselves ;)

Comment: I feel sorry for "y".  We keep telling it that it's sometimes a vowel, but it always gets left out in exercises like this.  That's probably why things like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31801150/letter-y-makes-text-processing-program-fail#comment51529281_31801150) happen....

Answer (score 1):

First things first, you either need to reset `r` back to zero either before the `while` loop or after.

Next simplifying the code.  If you're wanting to know how many vowels are in a `String`, you can use `String.replaceAll(String regex, String replacement)` to remove all non-vowel letters from the `String` then the length of the `String` will equal how many vowels you have.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String a = "banana";
    System.out.println(a.replaceAll("[^aeiouAEIOU]", "").length());
}
```

Result:

```
3
```

The `regex` pattern, in the `replaceAll()`, means to match any character that is not a lower/upper case vowel ([Regex Pattern Reference](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html)) and replace it with and empty string (remove it).  The result is a new String with nothing but vowels in it.

If `regex` is too complicating to understand, then walk the `String` like you're already doing, but check if each character is a vowel like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String vowels = "aeiouAEIOU";
    String a = "banana";

    int vowelCount = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < a.length(); i++) {
        String letter = Character.toString(a.charAt(i));
        if (vowels.contains(letter)) {
            vowelCount++;
        }
    }

    System.out.println(vowelCount);
}
```

You don't need to use `String.substring()` to extract a single character, that's what `String.charAt()` is for.  Also, instead of having an `array` of vowels, have a `String` of vowels so you can use `String.contains()` to see if the letter is a vowel.

As you can see, there are many ways to construct an algorithm to solve this problem.  Choose what makes best sense to you and helps you learn.

Answer (score 0):

try it like this

```
    String e [ ] = {"a", "e", "i", "o", "u"};
    String a = "banana";
    int r = 0;
    int b = 0;
    int c = 1;
    int z = 0;
    String q = " ";
    for(int i = 0; i < a.length(); i++){
        q = a.substring(b, c);
        b++;
        c++;
        r=0;
        while(r < e.length() ){
            if(q.equalsIgnoreCase(e [r])){
                z = z + 1;

            }
            r++;
        }

    }
    System.out.println(z);
```

I set r to 0 each time, I removed a comma after "u", and I added parenthesis after a.length, and I removed -1 after a.length()

Setting r to 0 is necessary because  r represents which of the vowels you are testing for.  So for each of the letters in the word, you are testing each of the vowels.  So after testing each letter (of banana) you have to set r to 0 so that it will start checking at "a" again (then e then i ...).   Then it moves on to the next letter in banana, so it needs to go back to "a" again.

And using e.length() instead of length() -1 is needed because otherwise it will never be testing for "u" .  It just happens to work because banana has no "u"'s

Answer (score 0):

You need to reset `r = 0` in your for loop.

```
for (int i = 0; i < a.length(); i++) {
    q = a.substring(b, c);
    b++;
    c++;
    r = 0;
    while (r < e.length - 1) {
        if (q.equalsIgnoreCase(e[r])) {
            z = z + 1;
        }
        r++;
    }
}
```

If you do not reset **r to 0** then you will end up value of **r to 4** when first time for loop executes (for character `b`). So when next time your for loop executes, value of r is 4 so every time it will check this condition `while (4 < e.length - 1)` which will result in false and it won't enter into while loop. So in case of `banana`, it will execute while for `b` but not for remaining characters `anana`.

If you are using any IDE then you can debug your code and see how values are changing.

For **Eclipse** : [Debugging With Eclipse](http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/9.2.8.v20150217/debugging-with-eclipse.html)

Answer (score 0):

Firstly format the code when you are sharing as a help to others.
Below is the running code. You should have run it and fixed the comma added to the array e. 
Just resetting the r index fixes it.

Here is a JDK 8 version

```
import java.util.*;

class Tester{
  public static void main(String args[]){
    String vowels [ ] = {"a", "e", "i", "o", "u"};
    String word = "bananae";

    int vowelCount = 0;
    Object[] vowelsInTheWord = Arrays.stream(vowels).filter(l -> word.indexOf(l) > -1).toArray();
    System.out.println(vowelsInTheWord.length);
  }
}
```

and your version fixed

```
class Tester{
  public static void main(String args[]){
    String e [ ] = {"a", "e", "i", "o", "u"};
    String a = "banana";
    int r = 0;
    int b = 0;
    int c = 1;
    int z = 0;
    String q = " ";
    for(int i = 0; i < a.length(); i++){
      q = a.substring(b, c);
      b++;
      c++;

      r = 0;

      while(r < e.length){
        if(q.equalsIgnoreCase(e [r])){
           z = z + 1;
        }
        r++;
      }
    }
    System.out.println(z);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the advice.